# How to execute items in Control Panel?

Tags: delphi

I want to execute an item from Control Panel (for example 'Screens Resolution').
[MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that it should be easy with WinExec.

These attempts will work (open the CPanel) but immediately after that the IDE will crash (crash in BorDbk150N.dll):

```
procedure ProjectTest1;
VAR s: AnsiString;
begin
 s:= 'c:\windows\system32\control.exe Desk.cpl,Settings';
 WinExec(pansichar(s), SW_NORMAL);
end;



procedure ProjectTest2;
VAR
  App        : String;
  Params     : String;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  try
   App    := 'c:\windows\system32\control.exe';
   Params := 'desk.cpl,Settings';
   FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo), 0);
   StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
   if NOT CreateProcess(NIL, PChar(App+' '+Params), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then RaiseLastOSError;
  except
    on E: Exception do
     Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

If you have a better method please let me know.

---

Using Delphi XE, Win 7

Comment: Your first attempt failed on `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: All works just fine here. I do note that your two versions are doing different things.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes, The second one is better because WinExec is marked as obsolete.

Comment: I meant that the second one does something different. The first executes `control.exe Desk.cpl` and the second executes `control.exe desk.cpl,Settings`. I don't understand why you are shouting.

Comment: Hi David - I changed them so both executes the same thing. They still crash the IDE.

Comment: `Desk.cpl,Settings` launches `Desk.cpl`. If you want to launch settings, use `Desk.cpl,Settings,@Settings`. This is not a problem for settings since desk.cpl launches with settings. But it would matter for themes for instance, `desk.cpl,Themes,@Themes` launches themes, but `desk.cpl,Themes` launches 'settings', 'desk.cpl' that is.

Comment: FWIW, when I said it works fine here, I meant that I can run your code just fine under the IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the control.exe method working fine myself, but since I felt the need to play, you can actually call the control panel item directly.  That said, you use the method that gets used when you [call control panel items using RUNDLL32](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/shellcpl.txt).

```
Display Properties (Settings):
    rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,,3
```

Code here.  I tested it against a few control panel items, whether it works universally is another story (and whether I got all the error checks done), but it worked in all the cases I threw at it, including all the desktop settings tabs.

```
function CallControlPanel(Handle: HWnd; FileName, FuncCall: WideString): Integer;
{
   calls a control panel item described in the function parms, if it supports
   being called using RUNDLL32.
   Handle: Valid window handle to parent form.
   FileName: Name of the Control Panel Applet, e.g. desk.cpl
   FuncCall: Alias call name for the tab requested e.g. "@Themes" or "1";
             What is put here is dependent on what the control panel app supports.
   Result: -1 if calls don't work, otherwise result of control panel call
}

const
  CPL_STARTWPARMSW = 10;
type
  cplfunc = function (hWndCPL : hWnd; iMessage : integer; lParam1 : longint;
         lParam2 : longint) : LongInt stdcall;
var
  lhandle: THandle;
  funchandle: cplfunc;
begin
  Result := -1;
  lHandle := LoadLibraryW(PWideChar(FileName));
  if LHandle <> 0 then
    begin
      @funchandle := GetProcAddress(lhandle, 'CPlApplet');
      if @funchandle <> nil then
        Result := funchandle(Handle, CPL_STARTWPARMSW, 0, LongInt(PWideString(funccall)));
      FreeLibrary(lHandle);
    end;
end;
```

Sample calls:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CallControlPanel(Handle, 'desk.cpl', '@ScreenSaver');
  CallControlPanel(Handle, 'desk.cpl', '@Themes');
  CallControlPanel(Handle, 'access.cpl', '1');  // doesn't support @ aliases
  CallControlPanel(Handle, 'access.cpl', '3');
  CallControlPanel(Handle, 'access.cpl', '5');
end;
```

Have fun.